# MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback is not working on window reload function at IE browsers

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a Asp.Net application, and we are using **MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback** property and set it to **true** for keeping scroll position on postbacks.

We are also using **Greybox** library for openning some new pages on popup.
On closing popup window, greybox call

> window.top.location.reload();

OR

> window.top.location = window.top.location;

for reloading top (parent) page.

But MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback property **not work correctly** at IE (ex. 10) browsers, and scroll 
go to top of page.

Is there a solution for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using [scrollsaver](https://github.com/hasheminezhad/scrollsaver) library, it is so useful.